# How can I avoid putting javascript in this EditorTemplate?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I wrote the following EditorTemplate that's loosely based off of some other SO questions and Google results:

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>
@{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression("", ViewData);
    string value;
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(metadata.EditFormatString)) {
        if(Model.HasValue) {
            value = String.Format(metadata.EditFormatString, Model.Value);
        }
        else {
            value = metadata.NullDisplayText;
        }
    }
    else {
        value = Model.ToString();
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", value, new { @class = "textBoxDate" })
<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.textBoxDate').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

The thing I don't like is that the script gets written below every `textBoxDate`. I understand why and I know that one possible solution would be to drop the script into a .js file and reference it on my page. That's not terribly difficult or anything but I was hoping there'd be a solution what would be a little bit more... seamless/magic (Why? Fun, it'd be neat, just because...). Any ideas?

Comment: @Xander Right way? I know of an alternative, I don't necessarily know if that alternative is the "right" way. Esp considering all of the 'automagic' things that MVC does. I was curious if there was some way to apply `.datepicker()` to these Date model items without writing a javascript function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think dropping the script into a .js file and referencing it on your page is the most fun and neat approach to this problem.

If you were looking for a less neat solution, you could add a couple HtmlHelper extensions to add register dependencies as the templating engine encounters them, then print out a bunch of script tags at the end of the page.

```
private const string requiredJavascriptIncludesContextItemsKey = "requiredJavascriptIncludesContextItemsKey";

public static void Require(this HtmlHelper html, string src)
{
    var collection = (HashSet<string>) html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[requiredJavascriptIncludesContextItemsKey] ?? new HashSet<string>();
    collection.Add(src);
    html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[requiredJavascriptIncludesContextItemsKey] = collection;
}

public static HtmlString RequiredJavascriptIncludes(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var src in (HashSet<string>) html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[requiredJavascriptIncludesContextItemsKey] ?? new HashSet<string>())
    {
        sb.Append(string.Format("<script type='text/javascript' src='{0}></script>", src));
    }

    return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

You could call the `@Html.Require` method within any template.  In your case, it'd be like this:

```
@model Nullable<DateTime>
@{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression("", ViewData);
    string value;
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(metadata.EditFormatString)) {
        if(Model.HasValue) {
            value = String.Format(metadata.EditFormatString, Model.Value);
        }
        else {
            value = metadata.NullDisplayText;
        }
    }
    else {
        value = Model.ToString();
    }
}
@Html.TextBox("", value, new { @class = "textBoxDate" })
@Html.Require(Html.Content("scripts/datepicker.js"))
```

Then, at the bottom of your base template page, you'd make the call to `@Html.RequiredJavascriptIncludes()` and all your js dependencies you've registered will be rendered as script tags at the end of the html document.

Comment: While not quite what I was looking for it's an interesting and well-detailed answer.

Comment: It's a bit more general-purpose than what your specific case called for, but it should handle your situation and any others similar to it.  If you get around to trying it, let me know how it works for you

Comment: If I'm understanding its effect correctly this will still print out a script tag for each datepicker box, no?

Comment: No.  Since the since the collection being stored in `HttpContext.Items` is a `HashSet`, the collection being rendered via `@Html.RequiredJavascriptIncludes()` is unique.  So, you can call the `@Html.Require` method as many times as you like with the reference to your javascript file and it will only render the script once.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I may not use but it definitely answered my question and gave me some other ideas as to how to accomplish this if I wanted. Thank you!